# "Se es" vs "es" (Traduciendo "it's like that")

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, cópulas, oraciones-impersonales

Pensando en cómo traducir la frase inglesa:

> It's like that, how could it be different?

Llegué a la frase española

> Es así, ¿cómo puede ser distinto?

Pero no sé si es esta un situación en la que se debería usar:

> Se es así, ¿cómo puede ser distinto?

Puede que haya un traducción mejor que todas estas. Sin embargo, empecé a pensar en cuándo se tiene que (o se debe) usar "serse" en vez de "ser".

Agredecería cualquier recomendación en relación a la traducción que puse, así como consideraciones sobre el uso de "serse" vs "ser".

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendación: No uses serse. El verbo ser no es reflexivo y no tiene complemento directo. No se me ocurre ninguna situación en la que "se es" sea correcto.

La primera traducción que has puesto es correcta. La segunda es incorrecta.

---

EDIT: Tal como walen menciona en su comentario, mi explicación no es ni completamente correcta ni está justificada con ninguna fuente. Así que trataré de corregir este error:

En el diccionario de la real academia española (links [aqui](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm%7CXe5NPsQ) y [aqui](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=4M7BtboGiD6n4FCqUu)) vemos que el verbo ser tiene varios valores. Puede ser:

- copulativo: Esta es la forma utilizada en el ejemplo de la pregunta. Un uso reflexivo no viene definido por el DRAE.
- intransitivo: En esta forma está permitido utilizar la construcción arcaica "érase" en narraciones y según [este](http://onomazein.letras.uc.cl/Articulos/9/5_Contreras.pdf) documento acerca del uso del "se" de [Lidia Contreras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidia_Contreras), esto puede ser una forma reflexiva:

> Por último, la Ac. nos dice (§ 277 d) que “el verbo ser admite
>   también la construcción reflexiva… significando con ella la participación
>   del sujeto [óntico] en la realización de lo significado por el
>   predicado; 
>   [...]
>   . Ej.: Érase una vez un rey que tenía…

- enfatico: Este uso no lo conozco, porque no lo he utilizado nunca. Pero no parece ser reflexivo
- auxiliar: Voz pasiva y la construcción "ser de". Ambas no son reflexivas.

Comment: "Se es lo que se es, no se puede ser otra cosa" ¿Pretende esto ser un ejemplo del uso de ser como verbo reflexivo? Porque si te fijas un poco, no lo es. Respecto a que debería incluir fuentes, cierto. Voy a buscarlas

Comment: Tengo que darte la razón. He corregido mi respuesta para hacerla un poco menos categórica y he añadido las fuentes que he podido encontrar.

Answer (score 1):

Como explicó @walen en sus comentarios, "se es" puede ser válido; es una construcción *[impersonal](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables)*:

> *Oraciones Impersonales:* Se llaman así por carecer de sujeto gramatical. Esta construcción puede darse con verbos intransitivos (*Se trabaja mejor en equipo*), con verbos copulativos (*Se está mejor solo que mal acompañado*) o con verbos transitivos, cuando llevan un complemento directo de persona precedido de la preposición a (*Se busca a los culpables del crimen*).

Pero en tu frase, el *se* está de más.  Consideremos un posible contexto de tu frase:

> Los exámenes son diferentes cada año.  Por lo tanto, no debes limitarte a mirar los exámenes anteriores, si quieres estar seguro de sacar un cien. Es así [el sistema educativo], ¿cómo puede ser diferente / de otro modo?  Por lo tanto, te aconsejo trabajar también con un buen libro de texto que dé un trato comprehensivo y completo de la materia.

Ahora veamos un ejemplo del buen uso de "se es".  Como ejemplo te ofrezco el [título de un artículo](https://www.vix.com/es/btg/curiosidades/7128/hasta-que-edad-se-es-adolescente):

> ¿Hasta qué edad se es adolescente?

Esta frase es equivalente a

> ¿Hasta qué edad es uno adolescente?

Nota que si hubiéramos puesto

> ¿Hasta qué edad es adolescente?

entonces la pregunta sería sobre una persona en particular, por ejemplo: ¿Hasta qué edad Lucas saldrá de la adolescencia?